# How to dump function parameter values of stack trace on Android dalvik JVM?

Tags: java, android, exception, jvm, stack-trace

When exception is caught, we can call Throwable.printStackTrace() to dump the stack trace. But I'd like to also dump each frame's parameters' value on the stack trace. Is this possible on Android's dalvik JVM? 
Exception stack example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxx.activity.OperationActivity.showError(OperationActivity.java:879)
    at com.xxxx.activity.SearchActivity.showList(SearchActivity.java:611)
    at com.xxxx.activity.OperationActivity.checkState(OperationActivity.java:756)
    at com.xxxx.activity.SearchActivity$14.handleMessage(SearchActivity.java:627)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I want to print all the function parameter values for each frame on stack trace, for example: the parameter values of com.xxxx.activity.OperationActivity.showError() function.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [StackTraceElement](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) Android dalvik does not store this information, it is only available in debug mode.

Comment: Babibu, do you mean i can get the parameter values in debug mode? Could you give more details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bettermanlu It is very basic about debugging. You should read about Java Debugging and how to work with breakpoints. Here is one [site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs108/JavaTools/eclipse-guide/) I found.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you mean compiling the app with debug = true, then we can get var values for each stack frame by writing some java code at runtime. Thanks again.